# Array Initialization

Tags: c++

I am trying to assign values within an array within the condition of a for loop:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int* c;
int n;
int main()
{
    scanf("%d", &n);
    c = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; c[i] = i++  )
    {
        printf("%d \n", c[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, I am not obtaining the desired output, for n = 5, `0 1 2 3 4`. Instead, if I am using the instruction, `c[i] = ++i`, I am obtaining the output `-842150451 1 2 3 4`. Could you please explain me we does my code behave like this and how can I correct it?

Comment: You may be compiling this with a C++ compiler, but be aware that you're not actually making use of any C++ features. An idiomatic C++ solution would involve `cin`, `vector` and `cout` rather than `scanf`, an array, and `printf()`.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < n; c[i] = i++  )` should be  `for (int i = 0; i<n && (c[i]=i)<n;  i++  )` meh it got ugly

Comment: weird thing was that the great comment part came when the for-loop was incorrect since it had off-by-1 access to the array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value of the expression `++i` is the value *after* `i` has been incremented. So if it started at 0, you assign value 1 the first time and so on. You can see *where* the value got assigned, but asking *why* it got assigned there opens a can of worms.

Using `i` in an expression where `i` is modified via `i++` *or* `++i` is undefined behavior unless there is a so-called "sequence point" in between the two. In this case, there isn't. See [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) for this rather complicated part of the language.

Although the behaviour is undefined by the standard, and may not be consistent from one run to another, clearly your program has done *something*. Apparently it didn't assign to index 0 at all (at least, not before the first print, which is understandable considering that the loop body happens *before* the last part of the "for"), so you got whatever just so happened to be in that raw memory when it was allocated to you. It assigned `1` to index `1` and so on.

This means that it may also have attempted to assign the value `5` to `c[5]`, which is a class of bug known as a "buffer overrun", and more undefined behavior on top of what you've already got. *Attempting* to assign to it probably overwrites other memory, which on any given day may or may not contain something important.

The fix is to assign some value to `c[0]`, and don't try to assign to `c[5]`, which doesn't exist anyway, and don't try to invalidly use `i` "at the same time as" incrementing it. Normally you'd write this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    c[i] = i;
    printf("%d \n", c[i];
}
```

If you're desperate for some reason to assign in the third clause of a for loop, you could use the comma operator to introduce a sequence point:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; c[i] = i, ++i) {
}
```

But of course if you do that then you can't print the value of `c[i]` in the loop body. It hasn't been assigned yet, because the third clause isn't evaluated until the end of each loop.

You could also try `c[i] = i+1, ++i`, but *not* `++i, c[i] = i` because then we're back to trying to assign to `c[5]`, on the last iteration.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there's no deterministic explanation to the behavior of both `c[i] = i++` and `c[i] = ++i` since both produce undefined behavior. They violate the requirements of 5/4.

Comment: @AndreyT: yes, I'm describing what must have happened given plausible behavior of actual implementations, but I didn't make that very clear. Am fixing.

Comment: below the question I showed how to desperately assign c[i] into the loop. A bit ugly, though.

Comment: @bestss: yes, yours follows the title of the question ("assign in the condition"). Mine follows the code example. Hopefully between us we've covered the whole realm of pointlessness.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to understand that the last part of the for loop is executed at the *end* of each iteration, so the reason you see this:

```
-842150451 1 2 3 4
```

Is because you print `c[0]` before it is assigned, so the value could be anything.  The rest falls into line as expected.

Lesson; don't be sneaky and stuff things into the last part of the for loop like that.  Make your code clear and simple:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i  )
{
    c[i] = i;
    printf("%d \n", c[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you are claiming that you want to assign the values "within the condition of the loop". In `for` loop the condition is the second part of the header (`i < n` in your case). You are performing the assignment in the third part, which is *not* a condition. So, why are you saying that you want to assign the values within the condition, and yet not doing that?

Secondly, expressions like `c[i] = i++` or `c[i] = ++i` do not have any defined behavior in C++ language. In C++ it is illegal to modify a variable and at the same time read it for any other purpose without an intervening sequence point. Yet, you are doing exactly that. There's no meaningful explanation for the behavior of your code. The behavior of your code is *undefined*. It can do anything for any random reason.

Thirdly, initializing anything in the `for` condition is generally not a good idea. Could you explain in more detail what you are trying to do and why? Without it it is hard to come up with anything meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `c[i] = ++i` produces undefined behavior.  It's undefined to both `++` a value (pre or post) and use it again within the same expression.  In this case it appears that `++i` is being evaluated before anything else and causing the execution to essentially be

```
c[1] = 1;
c[2] = 2;
...
```

This means `c[0]` is never initialized and instead has essentially a garbage value.  It seems like the order you want is

```
c[0] = 0;
c[1] = 1;
```

To get this ordering you'll need to separate the initialization and increment into separate statements.

```
c[i] = i;
i++;
```

Comment: The same problem. The behavior of both `c[i] = i++` and `c[i] = ++i` is *undefined* in C++ language. Both violate the requirements of 5/4.  Changing it back and forth will not help anything.

Comment: @AndreyT I can never remember if this behavior is undefined or just "behavior to be avoided".  I'll update to reflect the undefined nature of the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your fundamental problem is how the statements in the for(;;) structure get broken down and executed.  The for(st1; st2; st3) structure is intended to be identical to:

```
st1;
while (st2) {
    <body>
    st3;
}
```

Therefore, your 3rd statement, `c[i] = i++`, gets executed *after* the `printf` statement and you're printing uninitialized data.

The pre-increment vs. post-increment issue is obscuring this.